# Не понимаю что происходит[vk.api Java]

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Не могу понять что происходит и как мы вывели списки друзей.

```
listFrands  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);//Инициализация переменной вывода друзей
VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst. FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));//Выводит начальное и конечное имя
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        VKList list  = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
        listFrands.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Инициализируем переменную типа ListView, найдя этот элемент разметки по ID.
2. Формируем запрос к АПИ к его методу "друзья" с параметрами первого и последнего имени
3. Исполняем запрос, присваивая слушатель выполнения оного.
4. В последнем получаем список данных типа VKList из ответа сервера
5. Создаём адаптер для отображения в ListView, передавая в него контекст, разметку для элемента списка и сам список данных из п.4.
6. Присваиваем созданный адаптер ListView